# Prove inequality $\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+a}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}\geq(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I cannot prove the following inequality.

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers.Prove that:
>   $\dfrac{a^3}{b+c}+\dfrac{b^3}{c+a}+\dfrac{c^3}{a+b}\geq(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2. $

I tried to use Cauchy inequality. I think the functions $f(a,b,c)=\dfrac{a^3}{b+c}+\dfrac{b^3}{c+a}+\dfrac{c^3}{a+b}$ and $g(a,b,c)=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$ are  symmetric with respect to $a,b,c.$

Comment: You are right concerning the symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cauchy inequality:$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+a(b+c)\geq2a^2(1)$$
$$\frac{b^3}{a+c}+b(a+c)\geq2b^2(2)$$
$$\frac{c^3}{a+b}+c(a+b)\geq2c^2(3)$$
$$(1)+(2)+(3):\frac{a^3}{b+c}+a(b+c)+\frac{b^3}{a+c}+b(a+c)+\frac{c^3}{a+b}+c(a+b)\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{a+c}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}+2(ab+bc+ac)\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{a+c}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ac))$$
$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{a+c}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}\geq (a^2-2ab+b^2)+(b^2-2bc+c^2)+(a^2-2ac+c^2)$$
$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{a+c}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}\geq(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$$

Comment: I don't think it is Cauchy.  It is simply the AM GM

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}&\dfrac{a^3}{b+c}+\dfrac{b^3}{c+a}+\dfrac{c^3}{a+b} - (a-b)^2-(b-c)^2-(c-a)^2 \\ =& \sum\limits_{cyc} \left(\frac{a^3}{b+c} - 2a^2 +a(b+c)\right) \\ =& \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{a(a-b-c)^2}{b+c} \ge 0 \end{align}$$